# Where can I find the list of default permissions granted to Network Service, Local Service, Local System and Application Pool?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I am talking about Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

Where can I find the list of default permissions granted to Network Service, Local Service, Local System and Application Pool service account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Local System` can, by definition, do *anything* on the system. Hey, it's the operating system itself, what else could you expect? :-)

`Local Service` is just like a standard *local* user account with no administrative privileges; so it can run programs, and it has the additional right to log on as a service (as running services is exactly what it's used for), but it can't access network resources in a domain environment.

`Network Service` is exactly as above, but it *can* also access network resources in a domain; when it does, it authenticates against remote computers using the machine's domain account.

More detailed info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686005(v=vs.85).aspx.

This also has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/the-difference-between-the-local-system-account-and-the-network-service-accou.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can always run security configuration and analysis wizard and load a default setup security template and see exactly what's configured for each service.